# JavaFX LoadException when loading GridPanes inside of a StackPane initialize

Tags: java, javafx

Just as a quick explanation I'm just trying to set up a StackPane that contains two GridPanes, one right on top of each other. As you may be able to tell from the class names I'm trying to make a strategy game and I'd like to have a GridPane that acts as the background environment and then a GridPane on top of that that stores player units and that will capture all click events.

I've gotten the StackPane to load no problem but then I try to load both the environment GridPane and the unit GridPane inside the StackPane's initialize function and I keep getting a LoadException from that. I tried a few different things with the paths but that didn't change anything.

Here's where I'm currently at:

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    try {
        StackPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/battleGrid/BattleGrid.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 700));
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

BattleGridController.java
    package application.battleGrid;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import application.Main;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.LoadException;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class BattleGridController {

@FXML
private StackPane stack;

  public void initialize() {
    try {
        GridPane environmentGrid = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/environmentGrid/EnvironmentGrid.fxml"));
        GridPane unitGrid = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/unitGrid/UnitGrid.fxml"));
        stack.getChildren().addAll(environmentGrid, unitGrid);
    } catch (LoadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

BattleGrid.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="application.battleGrid.BattleGridController">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</StackPane>
```

UnitGrid.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="application.unitGrid.UnitGridController">

</GridPane>
```

EnvironmentGrid.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="application.environmentGrid.EnvironmentGridController"
        gridLinesVisible="true">

</GridPane>
```

There's currently nothing in the controllers for the environment and unit grid so there should be no issues there.

Here's the stack trace:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/markbluemer/Documents/workspace2/GridPanePractice/bin/application/battleGrid/BattleGrid.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:17)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.battleGrid.BattleGridController.initialize(BattleGridController.java:19)
... 25 more
```

General Project Structure:

- src

  - application

    - Main.java
    - battleGrid

      - BattleGridController.java
      - BattleGrid.fxml
    - environmentGrid

      - EnvironmentGridController.java
      - EnvironmentGrid.fxml
    - unitGrid

      - UnitGridController.java
      - UnitGrid.fxml

Edit:

Changed

```
FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/unitGrid/unitGrid.fxml"));
```

to

```
FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("/application/unitGrid/UnitGrid.fxml"));
```

Same issue still occuring

Comment: Issue resolved. In the fxml files the fx:id was never set. Therefore when trying to call 'stack' in the BattleGridController a NullPointerException was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is loading this:

```
Main.class.getResource("/application/unitGrid/unitGrid.fxml")
```

However you are stating it's name has an UPPER case "U"

UnitGrid.fxml

Try changing to case sensitive loading.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that mistake. Even with the change though I'm getting the same error. Is it wrong to assume that getResource is already case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is indicating that the Location is not set. It means that the resource path is not found by the FXMLLoader. As suggested by the purring pigeon make those changes.

**UPDATE**

To load the resource use the CurrentThread,

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("fxml_file_path")
```

Comment: I realize that the issue is the resource path but cannot find a reason why. I've made the change noted by purring pigeon but the error is still occurring.

Comment: can you please add the project structure, we will get clarity on how to load the resources?

Comment: Package structure added

Comment: Found the issue, looks like I had just forgotten to set the fx:id in the fxml files. The 'stack' I was trying to call was thus null.